# How to block user after 3 login attempts using Django rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django-rest-framework for my projects.

I wanted that when users intend to login and get the access token, if user enter wrong username or password for third time, their accounts get deactivated and an email containing activation link would be send to their email. Anyone can guide me to implement this scenario?

## models.y

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email   = self.normalize_email(email)
        mobile_number   = mobile_number
        user    = self.model(email=email, mobile_number= mobile_number **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, mobile_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_active=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, mobile_number, password, **extra_fields)

        
class User(AbstractUser):
    username    = None
    email       = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, validators= [validate_email])
    mobile_number   = models.CharField(_("mobile number"), max_length=11, unique = True, validators= [validate_mobile_number])

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile_number']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

## serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
    class Meta:
        model   = User
        fields  = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile_number', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
    
    
    def validate_mobile_number(self, value):
        if mobile_number_pattern.match(value):
            return value
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Mobile number pattern is not correct.')

class LoginSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    email = serializer.ChaerField()
    password = serializer.CharField()
    def validate(self, data):
        
        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email= email, password= password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    data["user"] = user
                else:
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError("User is deactivated.")
            else:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError("unable to login")
        else:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("Must provide email and password both.")
        return data
```

## Views.py (api views)

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
form .serializers import LoginSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data= request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception= True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
        login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"Token": token.key}, status= 200)
```

Comment: maybe add in database column for this variable and update it after every wrong login. And during every login (even next day)  check if it 3 and don't login. If someone use correct value before it will be 3 then reset it to 0 in database so next time it can try 3 times again.

Comment: Look into [django-axes](https://pypi.org/project/django-axes/)